# What should I do if I think my question has been mistakenly moved to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently had a question get moved from Super User to Stack Overflow, and I believe it was done so erroneously. Whoever moved my question probably just glanced at my question, saw some code and decided it was for Stack Overflow.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Please only use code blocks for code. Site names are not code. Could you post the question link so we can have a look at it?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204829/when-windows-cursor-has-the-spinning-animation-what-is-actually-happening) was correctly migrated. It is off-topic for SU, but on-topic for SO.

Comment: @CodyGray Why do you think so?

Comment: Um, because the details of how the window manager decides to show busy cursors is a programming question that requires specialized expertise, not something that a general computer enthusiast or power user is going to be able to answer. Furthermore, your repro case is *code*, which requires a programmer to compile and test. This is not the type of question that an end-user would ask. However, you have a perfect [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), making it an excellent SO question.

Comment: Okay thank you for explaining, however my question still remains, what is the course of action if someone believes that their question has been mistakenly moved?

Comment: Yeah, of course. I do not know the answer to that question, which is what you're actually asking. That's why I posted a comment, rather than an answer. :-)

Comment: The app did not handle GUI messages in a timely manner.  Any developer with any experience of an event-driven GUI would be able to answer, as would Google.  I agree that it should not have been migrated.

Comment: @Martin The fact that "any developer...would be able to answer" is *exactly* why the question was correctly migrated to Stack Overflow from Super User.

Answer (score 1):

The first step should be to read the question as written and see if it even remotely reflects what you want to ask.

To get a question migrated you need three other people agree that question actually belongs to another site, and in case of a non-default migration get at least one (likely several) diamond moderators to agree with migration. With such a high requirement there is a very good chance that what is *written* in the question is on topic on the destination site, but not what you wanted to ask to start with. Additionally, proper migration somewhat guarantees that questions have a reasonable chance to be good fit for the destination site and at very least is on-topic there.

After you stare at the question enough and double checked rules on both sites you should have roughly the following outcomes

- indeed the question is what I want to ask and it fits the new site better - be happy and wait for an answer
- the question is actually asking something very different from your goal - asking a new question on the original site is likely the most reasonable option. Whether you want to keep the original one on the destination site depends on whether you expect the question to stand on its own (keep and enjoy upvotes) or likely require a lot of attention and you are not interested in it (just delete<sup>*</sup>)
- indeed the question is what you wanted to ask, but it is totally off-topic on the new site - I'd delete it and go to ask on the original's site meta why the community decided to migrate the question. I would not repost it or flag for reverse migration before sorting that out.

In case of a linked question it does indeed look like a good fit for SO and is totally off-topic on SU. Carefully reading what is on-topic on each site should have clarified that.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>I assume that a user can self-delete migrated questions, if it is not possible flag for moderator attention with a clear reason why you want it to be deleted.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the following text, source site is where the question started out and target site is where it is now.

Migrations can be reversed but

1. questions should only have been be migrated if they were off-topic on the source site and some SMEs (Subject Matter Experts) on that site already made that determination.
2. migrated questions must be off-topic on the target site in order to be returned to the source site.
3. there's a time limit 30 days in which a migration can be reversed. After that its stub is deleted on the source site.

There is a [migration FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) on the global Meta and that tells us

> A question will be considered rejected by the target community after it has already been migrated if, on the target site, it gets closed for any reason other than as a duplicate, or deleted (provided it wasn't already closed as a duplicate or merged), while the migration stub on the original site still exists (hasn't been deleted).
>
> When a question which was already migrated gets rejected later, the entire process of the migration is reversed, except the original question will remain closed as off-topic. All the answers are returned to the origin site and undeleted, and are subsequently deleted on the target site*. Also, the rejected question on the target site will be locked, then automatically deleted 30 days later by a weekly script.

Firstly edit the question to make sure it's clear that it's off-topic on the target site and simultaneously on-topic on the source site because that's a prerequisite to send it back.

To get the question back on the source site we'd then need to reverse the migration and to do that you vote or flag the question for closure. If other people agree it's off-topic here and also vote to close, it will then be returned (closed) to the source site where you can then vote or flag it for reopening on that site.

Moderators on this site can close a question with one vote so if you can persuade one of those to close this question here you just need to get it reopened on the source site. Of course they'd have to agree it was off-topic here and they may also ask the moderators on the source site if they want it back and refuse to migrate it if the source site moderators indicate not to do so.

Answer (score -2):

> What can I do in this situation?

You raise a moderator flag and indicate you believe your question was migrated by mistake or in error.  If you have enough reputation, you can flag the question to be migrated back to the community or close the question which will throw it back to the original community.

However, as pointed out, in this case the migration was the proper action.  If you were to send that particular question back to Super User it would be closed.